# django model aggregate fliter by different time

Tags: django, filter, model, aggregate

the model as below:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):

    login_id=models.CharField(db_column='login_id',max_length=50,unique=True)
    passport_name=models.CharField(db_column='passport_name',max_length=50)
    identity_id=models.CharField(db_column='identity_id',max_length=50,null=True)
    company=models.CharField(db_column='company',max_length=50,null=True)

    ctime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='ctime', blank=True, null=True)
    utime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='utime', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "user_info"


class UserViewpoint(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(db_column='title',max_length=100)
    userid=models.ForeignKey(UserInfo,db_column='userid',to_field='login_id',related_name='rel_tg_viewpoint')
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='ctime', blank=True, null=True)
    utime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='utime', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "user_viewpoint"



class UserRelationHistory(models.Model):
    """docstring for TgRelationHistory"""

    adviser_id=models.ForeignKey(UserInfo,to_field='login_id',db_column='adviser_id',related_name='rel_tg_relation_history')
    common_id=models.CharField(db_column='common_id',max_length=100)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='ctime', blank=True, null=True)
    utime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='utime', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "user_relation_history"
```

i want to get result like this:
user_id,count_viewpoint,count_relation_new,count_relation_utilnow

count_realtion_new:new realtions when user_relation.ctime in (start,end)

count_relation_utilnow:total realtions where  user_relation.ctime < end

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this docs in the following link: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/

You can perform everything using Django ORM what you can do with an relational database.

Comment: i have already read the docs but find no way to implement like this,                                                                                                           select ui.login_id
,count(distinct r_current.common_id) as count_realtion_new
,count(distinct r_current.common_id) as count_relation_utilnow 
 from 
user_info ui left join (select * from user_relation_history where ctime = thatday) r_current on ui.login_id = r_current.adviser_id
left join (select * from user_relation_history where ctime <= thatday) urh
 on ui.login_id = urh.adviser_id
 group by ui.login_id.  thank u

Comment: What is TgInfo in your foreignkey here. I am not able to see the model.
Check this description please: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: oh sorry ! TgInfo is wrong,the right is UserInfo,i have fix it